# Is it possible to insert several documents to a MongoDB-collection with a single insert() call?

Tags: json, mongodb, insert, database

I defined 2 variables in the interactive shell of MongoDB:

```
a = {"letter": "a"}
b = {"letter": "b"}
```

Now I'd like to add them to a collection `newColl` in the database `stackoverflow`:

```
use stackoverflow
db.newColl.insert(a)
db.newColl.insert(b)
```

I was wondering, if it is possible to insert both documents in one go, for example like:

```
// Not working!
db.newColl.insert(a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put both docs into an array it will work:

```js
db.newColl.insert([a, b])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use arrays:

```
db.collection.isert([doc1:adsadad, doc2:asdad, etc, etc])
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/